# Getting name of uploaded file

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I'm writing a script to deal with forms. For now I don't have a database setup, so I'm testing using Session::flash.

Everything is working great, but I can't get the name of the file that gets saved, and I will need it to have it saved on database and then create a download link with it for another user.

I tried several ways and can't seem to make it work.

```
public function AltComiss(Request $request)
    {

        $name1 = array( ($request->input('test')),
                        ($request->input('test1')), 
                        ($request->input('test2')), 
                        ($request->input('test3')), 
                        ($request->input('test4')) ); 

        for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++) { 

            if (($request->input('comiss'.$i)) !== null) {
            array_push($name1, ($request->input('comiss'.$i)));
            array_push($name1, ($request->input('desconto'.$i)));
        }

        }

        array_push($name1, ($request->input('test7')));

        Session::flash('allInput',$name1);

        if ($request->hasFile('file2')) {
            $file = $request->file('file2');
            $destinationPath = 'altComiss';

            $filename = 'AlteraComissao-' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $file->storeAs($destinationPath, $filename);


            array_push($name1, $filename);

        }


        return redirect('alteracaocomissao');

    }
```

Everything is working great, all inputs get saved on Session(which later will be inserted into DB), and the file does get uploaded where I want it. But I can't save the filename, which I will need to retrieve it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing `$filename` to an array `$name1`.  It looks like you're using `$name1` on another page since you're flashing that data to the session.

The problem is you're flashing the data to the session before you push `$filename`.

Flash `$name1` to the session after you push `$filename` to `$name1`, or store `$filename` somewhere else.  You don't seem to be using that variable anywhere else.

Comment: You are exactly right! I'm sorry, been on this script for a few hours and this is really a silly mistake, I'm embarrassed..! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
   $file = $request->file('file2')->getClientOriginalName();
```

You should try this approach to get the name. Run in a similar problem like yours recently.